# Gitlab CI. Change variable in builded pipeline (for a manual job)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I'm developing embedded projects (fpga, mcu, dsp etc). And i have CI/CD where i can run pipelines and manual jobs inside that pipelines after they builded, like that:

```
"deploy-load":
  stage: deploy
  timeout: 30 minutes
  script:
    - cd sw/$PRJ
    - make run addr=$REMOTE_ADDR
  dependencies:
    - build
  rules:
    - if: $JTAG == "load"
      when: manual
```

So i have two variable that i need to set up: JTAG and REMOTE_ADDR. And i'm just cirious do gitlab cicd have the option where i can edit this variables after pipeline is builded.
Purpose: i want to switch between remote server and i need change REMOTE_ADDR variable to do that. It is possible?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes since your job is manual you can click on the job and then provide variables and values. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/index.html#specifying-variables-when-running-manual-jobs. This will allow you to provide input vars for just this job. You should check the variable precedence rules https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#cicd-variable-precedence but manual pipeline vars occur very high in the chain so will override most other vars.

[image]